# How to get more data from json array when a value in option tag is selected jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to display more info of the museum when a museum name is clicked fro the option dropdown box. I am getting my data from a json array. I was able to populate the option box with the name of the museum but could not display more details. Could anyone please help me with this. I'm using jquery for this code.

```
function getMuseums() {

    var museumSelect = $("<select id=\"museumlist\" name=\"museumlist\" onChange=\"getMuseumInfo()\" />");
    var info = $("<span>Select Museum: </span>")

    $.get("museums.php",function(data,status) {
        var response = '';
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        museums = json.museums;
        $.each(museums, function (index, item) {

            $('<option />').attr({"value" : index}).text(item.museum_name).appendTo(museumSelect);

            /*response += "<option value='"+index+"'>" + item.museum_name + "</option>";
            $("#museumlist").html(response);*/

        });

        $('#content').empty().append(info, museumSelect);
        $("<div id=\"museumDetails\" />").appendTo("#MuseumDiv");

        getMuseumInfo()

    });
}

function getMuseumInfo() {
    var museum_id = $("#museumlist").val();
    selectedMuseumid = museum_id;
    $("#MuseumDiv").empty().append("<div id=\"museumDetails\"/>");

    var url = "museums.php?museum_id=" +escape(museum_id);

    $.get(url,function(data,status) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        museums = json.museums;

        var museum_name = museums.museum_name;
        var museum_description = museums.museum_description;

        var museumInfo = "<h3>" + museum_name + "</h3><p>" + museum_description + "</p>";

        $("#museumDetails").empty().append(museumInfo);

    });
}
```

Comment: I guess you're getting the details with getMuseumInfo function, is some error shown?

Comment: There is no error showing.

Comment: How are you calling your getMuseums function from HTML?

Comment: I'm calling the function in getMuseums function

Answer (score 0):

You can pass option value to your function as a parameter `getMuseumInfo(this.value)`:

```
  var museumSelect = $("<select id=\"museumlist\" name=\"museumlist\" onChange=\"getMuseumInfo(this.value)\" />");
```

And than you can use iterate through museums and check if index is the same as option value, and then print only properties for that item.

```
$.each(museums, function(index, item) {    
    if (index == id) {
      var museumInfo = "<h3>" + item.museum_name + "</h3><p>" + item.museum_description + "</p>";    
      $("#MuseumDiv").empty().append(museumInfo);
    }
});
```

But better check  working code (also turn on console in app):
[codePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wozxwq)

NOTE:
I make example of request to create JSON data. I make get request to url:
https://api.myjson.com/bins/58j10